# Open function creates weird square brackets when reading .Result file (using pycharm 64bit)

Tags: python, pycharm

[The Result Table.Result file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbDV4.png)
The file path  to which is getting inserted into the function.

```
def file_read(fname):
content_array = []
is_data_line = False
#v path doda //Result Table
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    txt = f.read()
    print(txt)

    for line in f.readlines():
        if is_data_line:
            line = line.split()
            content_array.append( (float(line[0]),float(line[2])) )
        else:
            if line == "[TableValues]\n":
                is_data_line = True
    return content_array

print(file_read(r'C:\Users\M0182965\PycharmProjects\EMC2.00\Result Table.Result'))  # WORKS NOT
print(file_read(r'C:\\Users\\M0182965\\PycharmProjects\\EMC2.00\\Result Table.Result'))  # WORKS NOT
```

[Wrong: The data my function reads when inserted the  .result  file (this problem happens in 64bit pycharm. )This picture is the output of print(txt). Contains weird square brackets that mess up with the function. The print(txt) statement is only there for debugging purposes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sy2F.png)
The function outputs an **empty array []**.

[Correct: The data my program should read (32 bit pycharm does it, it also works when I rename the file to .txt. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that by code, and even if I could, The the original Result Table.Result file MUST NOT be changed. This picture is the output of print(txt). No weird squares)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i52Bw.png)
The **correct output is** the list below

| Frequency | Ant In Fwd |
| --- | --- |
| 20.00000000000E+0 | 276.18112860E+0 |
| 20.50000000000E+0 | 307.54523316E+0 |
| ... | ... |

**The result  file when opened in notepad**

```
[FileInfo]
Author=EMC32
Version=8.3
MeasClass=0 <No Class>
Start=20.00000000000E+6
Stop=80.00000000000E+6

[TurnTable]
Azimuth=0.0000000000E+0

[TableSettings]
TableType= 49 Result Table
IndicateDetector=1
Columns=11
Rows= 121
SaveResolution=0
BandsOption=0
ResultType= 0

[TableHeader]
Name=   Frequency   Imm Level-Pk/H  Ant In Fwd  Ant In Rev  VSWR    Gen Out Comment Modulation  Polarization    Height  Azimuth
Unit=   MHz V/m W   W       dBm             m   deg
ColTyp= 11 Frequency    18 Immunity Level   22 Transducer Level 13 Level    23 Meas Value   17 Generator Level  0 Text  0 Text  5 Polarization  27 Position 28 Azimuth
Detector=    0   3   2   2   2   2   0   0   0   0   0
Intpol=  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Format=  6   2   3   3   3   1   0   0   0   2   1
ColWidth=   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
ColVisible= 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
ColReport=  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1

[TableValues]
20.00000000000E+0   71.361716627E+0 276.18112860E+0 251.19327026E+0 42.186747983E+0 -5.4734012735E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
20.50000000000E+0   71.633896749E+0 307.54523316E+0 253.53271081E+0 20.727601924E+0 -5.7709953921E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
21.00000000000E+0   71.508344980E+0 342.74884502E+0 257.05555887E+0 13.927063094E+0 -5.4372383372E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
21.50000000000E+0   71.563696353E+0 380.91142586E+0 265.75105665E+0 11.140883256E+0 -4.9133552299E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
22.00000000000E+0   71.691399647E+0 419.46526145E+0 280.91569223E+0 10.010288726E+0 -4.7424914652E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
22.50000000000E+0   71.045903502E+0 446.71239183E+0 298.41249241E+0 9.9483737020E+0 -4.7424914652E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
23.00000000000E+0   70.457828027E+0 457.14713254E+0 316.83999663E+0 10.941358695E+0 -4.0095055528E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
23.50000000000E+0   71.299810538E+0 445.55364407E+0 327.76003702E+0 13.053368515E+0 -2.9079669061E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
24.00000000000E+0   70.370069530E+0 387.30936661E+0 304.71792339E+0 16.697957146E+0 -2.9079669061E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
24.50000000000E+0   71.679131834E+0 319.64432623E+0 265.41043880E+0 21.528797825E+0 -3.7767875786E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
25.00000000000E+0   71.864266350E+0 244.65888941E+0 208.36942822E+0 24.927370032E+0 -5.7046243101E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
25.50000000000E+0   71.720232666E+0 198.29465134E+0 169.78643908E+0 25.784027435E+0 -7.9685914943E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
26.00000000000E+0   71.585540379E+0 179.98611383E+0 153.28723836E+0 24.925227522E+0 -9.3177729467E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
26.50000000000E+0   71.567938283E+0 180.56476209E+0 151.86650557E+0 23.124104461E+0 -8.7606694612E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
27.00000000000E+0   70.906930770E+0 187.95331936E+0 152.65885476E+0 19.249216630E+0 -7.1788162495E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
27.50000000000E+0   70.810389761E+0 204.93304827E+0 157.43127039E+0 15.191045693E+0 -5.9000880719E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
28.00000000000E+0   71.369027205E+0 229.36703471E+0 164.53072067E+0 12.067662864E+0 -5.4356907864E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
28.50000000000E+0   71.749089443E+0 255.05685484E+0 169.75633878E+0 9.8589591809E+0 -5.8938019003E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
29.00000000000E+0   71.423208317E+0 275.11356206E+0 170.47001525E+0 8.3971286959E+0 -6.9650709315E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
29.50000000000E+0   71.674423996E+0 296.39167426E+0 173.45107667E+0 7.5102596975E+0 -7.7983168745E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
30.00000000000E+0   71.608984357E+0 310.54389797E+0 175.65236437E+0 7.0672007142E+0 -7.6283644406E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
30.50000000000E+0   70.488185548E+0 309.11636660E+0 177.80542191E+0 7.2789341393E+0 -6.5449942800E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
31.00000000000E+0   70.904206996E+0 318.64051843E+0 187.18756721E+0 7.5637467146E+0 -5.4080905704E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
31.50000000000E+0   70.846225343E+0 321.71847396E+0 196.90919649E+0 8.1886020983E+0 -4.7475444666E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
32.00000000000E+0   70.655419460E+0 316.03559512E+0 208.24855663E+0 9.6242441131E+0 -4.7475444666E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
32.50000000000E+0   71.719833217E+0 325.35388729E+0 233.12454418E+0 12.027502545E+0 -5.0296510810E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
33.00000000000E+0   71.629569099E+0 325.79768947E+0 251.68190935E+0 15.518737114E+0 -5.7874324644E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
33.50000000000E+0   71.749978231E+0 330.26382010E+0 271.64767981E+0 20.488590303E+0 -6.5670576335E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
34.00000000000E+0   71.594062879E+0 336.15919882E+0 287.17392235E+0 25.410461502E+0 -6.8380248354E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
34.50000000000E+0   71.181608763E+0 343.34837792E+0 296.48996581E+0 27.272766842E+0 -5.9328749883E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
35.00000000000E+0   70.363014246E+0 349.34055027E+0 297.49659543E+0 24.913093593E+0 -4.3342134938E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
35.50000000000E+0   71.255759677E+0 375.30383308E+0 307.84705266E+0 20.204983728E+0 -2.8090871118E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
36.00000000000E+0   70.981279382E+0 387.45654367E+0 302.58333134E+0 16.198753669E+0 -2.4177844549E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
36.50000000000E+0   72.054871758E+0 413.09696096E+0 300.56887098E+0 12.604891178E+0 -2.8543483629E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
37.00000000000E+0   71.829457831E+0 419.93783027E+0 284.10050127E+0 10.268518609E+0 -4.1498338757E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
37.50000000000E+0   72.088839519E+0 428.21019210E+0 269.52868970E+0 8.6789847916E+0 -5.7185594599E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
38.00000000000E+0   71.876173591E+0 422.87206838E+0 248.87197827E+0 7.5894297347E+0 -6.6103204424E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
38.50000000000E+0   71.173236934E+0 406.56220208E+0 225.85567115E+0 6.8534801733E+0 -5.8949060249E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
39.00000000000E+0   70.790912448E+0 390.52514291E+0 208.21163763E+0 6.4122596830E+0 -4.4078081777E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
39.50000000000E+0   70.515938921E+0 372.79149874E+0 194.70540157E+0 6.2123164069E+0 -3.4188872702E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
40.00000000000E+0   71.374051725E+0 364.50626734E+0 190.76117991E+0 6.2312674625E+0 -3.2018460165E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
40.50000000000E+0   72.043080782E+0 353.49965966E+0 189.63129025E+0 6.4744145495E+0 -3.9080826627E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
41.00000000000E+0   71.917920427E+0 337.30361834E+0 188.90610782E+0 6.9479672671E+0 -5.2734600970E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
41.50000000000E+0   71.646478552E+0 324.26867725E+0 190.02030026E+0 7.5289324155E+0 -6.6261638348E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
42.00000000000E+0   71.794240983E+0 317.28679661E+0 194.54810280E+0 8.2185612291E+0 -7.2471374070E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
42.50000000000E+0   71.597514578E+0 311.35869620E+0 196.79316025E+0 8.7567397813E+0 -6.8442883342E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
43.00000000000E+0   71.146059148E+0 306.50460228E+0 196.59207201E+0 9.0439202025E+0 -5.8297529966E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
43.50000000000E+0   70.972556522E+0 305.75671236E+0 195.06214697E+0 8.9367647839E+0 -4.8639811590E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
44.00000000000E+0   71.177303696E+0 307.16589939E+0 191.18948352E+0 8.4761027140E+0 -4.3701782579E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
44.50000000000E+0   72.758058280E+0 319.76505438E+0 191.17715748E+0 7.8190797705E+0 -4.3701782579E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
45.00000000000E+0   71.795535460E+0 309.79471175E+0 173.94141552E+0 6.9781439318E+0 -5.3109594839E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
45.50000000000E+0   71.700201560E+0 303.73790981E+0 158.20018973E+0 6.1863733132E+0 -6.5362996014E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
46.00000000000E+0   71.794783925E+0 296.18973284E+0 140.57497016E+0 5.4292211392E+0 -7.5590895807E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
46.50000000000E+0   71.557065132E+0 283.90954912E+0 120.32891480E+0 4.7310039244E+0 -7.3756541508E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
47.00000000000E+0   71.577119604E+0 273.09641557E+0 101.63165551E+0 4.1286976696E+0 -6.0935445592E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
47.50000000000E+0   71.257236590E+0 262.03119653E+0 83.343742828E+0 3.5868949627E+0 -4.8699053134E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
48.00000000000E+0   71.482587274E+0 259.99619967E+0 68.018492125E+0 3.0940114588E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
48.50000000000E+0   71.425938520E+0 271.97313040E+0 54.233920480E+0 2.6137120627E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
49.00000000000E+0   71.346300309E+0 323.31064203E+0 42.712599155E+0 2.1420333661E+0 -4.2408372572E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
49.50000000000E+0   71.224697473E+0 438.66905593E+0 35.633132274E+0 1.7972378163E+0 -3.4575457846E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
50.00000000000E+0   71.580439500E+0 506.88565413E+0 39.704707411E+0 1.7773003143E+0 -3.1107021791E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
50.50000000000E+0   71.492183862E+0 427.79135115E+0 47.207717202E+0 1.9948773423E+0 -3.9779305215E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
51.00000000000E+0   71.676295479E+0 347.23780321E+0 51.696483202E+0 2.2565263321E+0 -4.5616084760E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
51.50000000000E+0   71.662125193E+0 298.00805295E+0 53.725071235E+0 2.4758104700E+0 -4.7763695012E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
52.00000000000E+0   71.764579744E+0 270.10212440E+0 54.369207167E+0 2.6274926856E+0 -5.0312651272E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
52.50000000000E+0   71.886473443E+0 253.26431389E+0 53.508281110E+0 2.7012774189E+0 -5.5339989999E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
53.00000000000E+0   71.959844978E+0 241.52161275E+0 51.046150902E+0 2.7018575291E+0 -6.2127695145E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
53.50000000000E+0   71.881817448E+0 230.94842243E+0 46.825023068E+0 2.6382078769E+0 -6.8983579939E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
54.00000000000E+0   71.768689101E+0 221.12660594E+0 41.106452628E+0 2.5159028307E+0 -7.4158734773E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
54.50000000000E+0   71.677341468E+0 211.77612623E+0 34.206607153E+0 2.3439146282E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
55.00000000000E+0   72.543994063E+0 207.62469142E+0 27.503502270E+0 2.1444598188E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
55.50000000000E+0   71.754948783E+0 194.39316914E+0 19.727951883E+0 1.9349905051E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
56.00000000000E+0   70.419848478E+0 179.17606725E+0 12.896474389E+0 1.7333025761E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
56.50000000000E+0   70.407020418E+0 170.96412977E+0 8.1111045616E+0 1.5569393880E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
57.00000000000E+0   72.564834919E+0 173.28341569E+0 5.3556970159E+0 1.4266081546E+0 -7.7487301104E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
57.50000000000E+0   71.708639484E+0 160.65564867E+0 3.8212372266E+0 1.3646943288E+0 -8.3387398897E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
58.00000000000E+0   71.698012616E+0 152.11953879E+0 3.8085091208E+0 1.3759419868E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
58.50000000000E+0   72.829301867E+0 148.08190747E+0 4.4896656515E+0 1.4216679518E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
59.00000000000E+0   72.891316246E+0 140.00450164E+0 4.6898613120E+0 1.4480535385E+0 -8.7558957041E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
59.50000000000E+0   72.491465271E+0 132.55618607E+0 4.0514548180E+0 1.4237306212E+0 -8.9711762853E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
60.00000000000E+0   71.638429739E+0 127.48790957E+0 2.9672285567E+0 1.3600494020E+0 -9.1386888386E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
60.50000000000E+0   70.762023896E+0 126.92904135E+0 2.1440010810E+0 1.2987625150E+0 -9.1386888386E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
61.00000000000E+0   70.825244039E+0 132.86787829E+0 1.9129164418E+0 1.2726964138E+0 -8.7772517766E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
61.50000000000E+0   71.543288033E+0 143.70173114E+0 2.1196785255E+0 1.2764829843E+0 -8.3615079700E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
62.00000000000E+0   71.402734506E+0 152.22115048E+0 2.4028352805E+0 1.2873847520E+0 -7.9965484581E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
62.50000000000E+0   71.459587965E+0 162.15860515E+0 2.5657243743E+0 1.2877713976E+0 -7.5877824576E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
63.00000000000E+0   71.445314288E+0 171.88223808E+0 2.4827500540E+0 1.2732056860E+0 -7.2089502736E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
63.50000000000E+0   71.527662662E+0 182.25690877E+0 2.2382005597E+0 1.2492564947E+0 -6.8746404724E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
64.00000000000E+0   71.429178829E+0 192.06976278E+0 2.0626949247E+0 1.2312229682E+0 -6.5780316421E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
64.50000000000E+0   71.550465516E+0 203.99710301E+0 2.3370876476E+0 1.2397292470E+0 -6.2835875894E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
65.00000000000E+0   71.533119273E+0 216.24844837E+0 3.4316975132E+0 1.2882592305E+0 -6.0227712379E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
65.50000000000E+0   71.524779594E+0 230.12722472E+0 5.6937972719E+0 1.3733118824E+0 -5.8090231431E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
66.00000000000E+0   71.595217608E+0 245.97275192E+0 9.3832437887E+0 1.4854410062E+0 -5.6133790018E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
66.50000000000E+0   71.507446285E+0 262.07584817E+0 14.618943917E+0 1.6184205278E+0 -5.3227725760E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
67.00000000000E+0   71.483067801E+0 280.23024081E+0 21.371401333E+0 1.7630372501E+0 -4.8001993550E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
67.50000000000E+0   71.540190638E+0 300.26450761E+0 29.453980842E+0 1.9120505500E+0 -4.1152962201E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
68.00000000000E+0   71.536899020E+0 320.66975502E+0 38.261588800E+0 2.0554129363E+0 -3.5312536898E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
68.50000000000E+0   71.598106047E+0 341.56471502E+0 47.327547496E+0 2.1859198824E+0 -3.2483042073E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
69.00000000000E+0   72.349233654E+0 369.62726601E+0 57.030345155E+0 2.2938052910E+0 -3.2483042073E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
69.50000000000E+0   71.872776578E+0 384.50854885E+0 63.725903269E+0 2.3732709133E+0 -3.6418622796E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
70.00000000000E+0   71.683821238E+0 401.63448964E+0 69.177521818E+0 2.4189089892E+0 -3.8803053044E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
70.50000000000E+0   71.599887366E+0 419.44884224E+0 72.967253560E+0 2.4310315661E+0 -3.6406635854E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
71.00000000000E+0   71.453425038E+0 435.51488211E+0 74.486745612E+0 2.4104056504E+0 -2.9676382097E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
71.50000000000E+0   71.291992369E+0 451.55847742E+0 75.035365095E+0 2.3763209656E+0 -2.2616111734E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
72.00000000000E+0   71.481858490E+0 471.04131420E+0 75.163673955E+0 2.3303421637E+0 -1.8941898665E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
72.50000000000E+0   72.383024090E+0 502.24659371E+0 77.306497984E+0 2.2912501839E+0 -1.8941898665E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
73.00000000000E+0   71.632049924E+0 511.30495330E+0 77.274997556E+0 2.2720272347E+0 -2.3977758143E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
73.50000000000E+0   71.699397841E+0 530.14052032E+0 81.431230982E+0 2.2890534776E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
74.00000000000E+0   72.568104141E+0 562.73120675E+0 91.173998183E+0 2.3473795867E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
74.50000000000E+0   70.941209440E+0 558.67983988E+0 98.194915331E+0 2.4437649914E+0 -2.7804583408E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
75.00000000000E+0   71.317787606E+0 584.03382431E+0 114.84312458E+0 2.5934939440E+0 -2.2911512498E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
75.50000000000E+0   70.954624297E+0 597.21127726E+0 132.93581424E+0 2.7864372351E+0 -1.7285427531E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
76.00000000000E+0   70.774817496E+0 609.57338961E+0 153.74960192E+0 3.0178391714E+0 -1.1808139648E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
76.50000000000E+0   71.200163987E+0 626.86352429E+0 177.92582982E+0 3.2804710589E+0 -839.57927389E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
77.00000000000E+0   71.397408092E+0 633.35616169E+0 199.61400119E+0 3.5599513133E+0 -839.57927389E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
77.50000000000E+0   71.827184637E+0 639.58754805E+0 220.40020798E+0 3.8428987000E+0 -1.0273980618E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
78.00000000000E+0   72.187337859E+0 644.93804976E+0 238.77453062E+0 4.1080891683E+0 -1.4046938870E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
78.50000000000E+0   72.060087400E+0 640.65172522E+0 249.66231891E+0 4.3228294528E+0 -1.7755344304E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
79.00000000000E+0   70.367732374E+0 604.87968655E+0 242.82421868E+0 4.4584355505E+0 -1.7755344304E+0        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
79.50000000000E+0   70.436428002E+0 599.82698515E+0 243.16328398E+0 4.5051177609E+0 -713.11323154E-3        CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
80.00000000000E+0   71.153818237E+0 605.84844842E+0 242.00369667E+0 4.4350388401E+0 561.31370248E-3     CW  H   0.0000000000E+0 0.0000000000E+0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open(fname,'r',encoding="utf-16")
```

Cheacked encoding in notepadd ++